# How to stream audio from Android phone to another Android phone using bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-streaming, audiorecord, audiotrack

I'm trying to build a bluetooth walkie-talkie app for one of my classes but I can't seem to get it working correctly. I modified the BluetoothChat example (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) to try and fit my needs and I can successfully transmit voice recordings from one phone to another but it comes out very staticky. I'm using AudioRecord and AudioTrack for recording and playback.

I have these global variables

```
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private AudioTrack audioTrack = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;
```

and in my onCreate method I set the bufferSize and initialize the AudioTrack.

```
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, 
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Here is my code when the record/send button is pressed (I currently only have it to record 3 seconds of data.)

```
private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        int i = recorder.getState();
        if (i == 1)
            recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        enableButtons(false);
                        if(null != recorder){
                                isRecording = false;

                                recorder.stop();
                                recorder.release();

                                recorder = null;
                                recordingThread = null;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 3000);

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            writeOutAudioData();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
}

private void writeOutAudioData() {

    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];

    int read = 0;

        while (isRecording) 
        {
            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) 
            {
                    mChatService.write(data);
                    //TODO

            }
        }
}
```

Here is the code that handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }
```

here is the code for my handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if (D)
                Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to,
                        mConnectedDeviceName));
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            //byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            final byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            final byte bytes = (byte) msg.arg1;

            Thread audioPlay = new Thread()
            {
                public void run(){
                    audioTrack.play();
                    audioTrack.write(readBuf, 0, readBuf.length);
                    audioTrack.stop();
                }

            };
            audioPlay.start();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I just don't understand what the size of the byte[] buffer should be in the ConnectedThread class. Should I leave it at 1024 or change it to something else? And I can't figure out the correct way to read those incoming bytes and writing them into the AudioTrack for playback (without static).
I'm using Android 4.3 on one phone and 4.2.2 on the other.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: did find any work around

Answer (score 0):

I know its been about a year, but I had this problem also.

You must make sure that what you send is exactly what you want to send, and what you write to AudioTrack is exactly what you receive.  A simple test is to count sent bytes and compare to received (perceived received) bytes.

I believe the key is using the minimum buffer size calculated by your parameters for the audiotrack.

```
int minsize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

You can send the data in whatever chunk size you want, but you will see that its typically 1007 bytes for a bluetooth socket (this is what I see in my tests).  I suspect the best performance is going to be if you allow the socket to chunk for you, as its going to perform the check anyways, therefore you probably want to send the same `minsize`.

I'd also recommend changing your audio format to mono, unless your devices have binaural mics?

I'll admit that I didn't attempt to digest all of your code, but I think you have some unnecessary overhead with encapsulating the data in a message.  Its a data stream, i dont think it needs to be encapsulated.  I suggest using `BluetoothSocketServer` and `BluetoothSocket`.

Last note, as I am writing this up for any others who come across this.  Note that `AudioTrack.write()` in streaming mode WILL BLOCK unless you write the `minsize` data to it.  While this is explained on the android reference site, I want to emphasize its importance to avoid wasted time debugging deadlocks.